# Why would an Email be missing recipient email address's in headers?

Tags: email, exchange, outlook

We have 2 companies working out of the same Remote Desktop environment.

- **Company A** uses Office 365 for all emails and Office apps.
- **Company B** uses a 3rd party hosted Exchange for sending emails but utilizes the same Office 365 Apps on the terminal server as **Company
  A**.

We are seeing an issue where occasionally emails sent by users of **Company B** to users of **Company A** will contain only the recipients display name and will be missing the recipient email address/s from the headers.

The problem with this is when the user that has received the email hits reply all to one of these emails Outlook is resolving their email address from the display name and including them in the reply list, meaning they send an email to themselves. A trivial issue but an issue non the less.

An example of the headers when this issue occurs would look like this:

```
From: User1 <user1@example.com>
To: 'User2'
CC: 'User3'
```

An example of a normal Email with no issues would look like this:

```
From: User1 <user1@example.com>
To: 'User2' <user2@example.com>
CC: 'User3' <user3@example.com>
```

I can't find a common element between affected email's, they appear to occur from any users of **Company B** to any user of **Company A**. Initially i thought it would be something to do with the address book of users at **Company B** but after going through the GAL and personal address books, deleting and re adding entries made no difference so now I'm not so sure.

What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: Any updates on your issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, this issue occurs randomly when senders who locate in company B send mails to company A?

Does this issue occur to another recipients who outside company A?

What is the version of your outlook client in company A?

To narrow down this issue, run outlook in safe mode and check if this issue is related with add-ins, then see if this issue continues.

In addition, if we set "when replying a message do not include orginal message" in Outlook, it may not display any information about your original messages, check it and keep this setting in Outlook when you forward/reply the message.[image]